# Different post types arranged on one page

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, pages

Lets say I have a wp-site with three pages: "Home", "Project" and "About". "Home" and "About" are static pages, and "Project" has sub-pages.

I want to add content to the sub-pages, in form of posts, and then I want to easily arrange and organize the posts, and have a overview of which posts belong to which sub-page.

Whats the best way of doing this?

My own attempt was:

Custom Post Types for the types of posts that are put on the sub-page. I then used Advanced Custom Fields (plugin) to connect the subpage with each Custom Post Type, and with the Repeater extension I could rearrange them on the sub-page view.. But this gives no good overview of what is on the sub-page as each Custom Post only has its titel shown..

Comment: You might try using your own custom nav menu to easily arrange and organize the posts, like I drafted up [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/176529/26350).

Comment: Hmm. That seems interesting! I'll give it a go and get back with the results!

Comment: A hierarchical COT for projects would seem to fit your requirements.

Comment: It's kinda working good. Though I have a problem with the WP_Query, evern if the query has content (`var_dump($q)`) `have_posts()` returns false... Any clue? @birgire

Comment: @everlof ok great, notice that you must then use `$q->have_posts()`, not `have_posts()`. Maybe that's the issue?

Comment: Nope ;/  Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4af1265f358aaef49cb4 And $ids is `array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "55" [1]=> string(2) "50" [2]=> string(2) "65" } `

Comment: The query says `AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment')` which is strange since it's queried with `'post_type' = 'any'` Seems that it doesnt include Custom Post Types

Comment: Solved it.. I had "exclude_from_search" set to true.. Anyway, feel free to create a answer, I think ill use this solution, unless a big blocker shows up..

Comment: Good to hear you managed to find the cause of the problem. I will leave it up to you to answer or maybe close as duplicate ;-) @everlof